# How to debug spring-boot application with IntelliJ IDEA community Edition?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I'm having difficulties in debugging a Java spring-boot application on IntelliJ IDEA community Edition. The main problem is, that the IDE won't stop on a breakpoint, even the program surely executes through it. How can I make the the IntelliJ IDEA to stop on the breakpoint?

As additional information, here is my run configurations:

Maven configuration with a command as: spring-boot:run. Before launch I build the project.

Comment: Did you run it in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, I did.....

Comment: Here is a maven spring boot plugin http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html Have you tried it?

Comment: I have the spring-boot-maven-plugin. Though I don't have any configurations for it defined in pom.xml. Might try that one, if I understand it correctly mm...

Comment: @VilleMiekk-oja, if all is configured properly, open the "Maven Project" tab on the right side, and choose the `bootRun` option there with the right-click

Comment: ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use. The last option (address), what address should I use? The same as the application uses, or the one specified in the link? (5005)

Comment: @VilleMiekk-oja, it seems you could not close the previous start of the app clearly, or the port you are trying to use is busy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144772/discussion-between-ville-miekk-oja-and-andrew-tobilko).

Comment: I hav the same occasionaly in Ultimate. I am not quite sure what it it, some perhaps process still running, but normally quiting and restarting IJ helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only way I got it working was by creating a separate, remote debug configuration.

So go to edit configurations-> Remote -> +. Then start your application normally through intelliJ. Then switch to the newly created remote configuration. Instead of running it, press debug. Now debugger should be ready, and you can set breakpoints and the debugger will stop to them.

EDIT: For me the debug port was already enabled, but I see that this is not the case for everyone. If you get an error like

```
'Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"
```

Then you need to enable port on your app's pom.xml. Copied from @Gianluca Musa answer:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<configuration>
<jvmArguments>
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
</jvmArguments>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Kudos for @Gianluca Musa for pointing this out in his answer

Comment: Excellent solution; works also on my setup: IntelliJ 2018.2, Maven 3.5.4 to debug a spring-boot 1.3.6 app (Java 8). Kudos.

Comment: `Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"`

Comment: Still works fine for IntelliJ Ultimate version 2020.3

Comment: Works like a charm. Note that you also need to add `<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>`, otherwise it will fail with "artifactId of a plugin must be defined".

Comment: Still works on IntelliJ Community  2023.1.2, thaks

Answer (score 207):

**EDIT:** it does not work anymore from `Spring Boot 3+`. See [Ruik's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096708/how-to-debug-spring-boot-application-with-intellij-idea-community-edition#comment133138531_47064387)

---

tldr: You can try tweaking the command line like this:

```
spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.fork=false
```

Explanation:

When running the application in debug mode, the IntelliJ debugger attaches to the Java process that it starts itself (by appending the appropriate parameters, `-agentlib:jdwp` etc, to the Java command line).

Quite often, these Java processes might then fork a new instance, which is *not* getting the same parameters, and because it is in a separate process, is not connected to the debugger. This can be confusing.

The `spring-boot:run` Maven goal, in addition to forking a new JVM, creates even more confusion, because it sometimes does fork and sometimes doesn't, depending on the options it gets, among other things. Some of this can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#fork), but it's not always obvious.

You should first check whether the Java process actually is being debugged at all. When you start the application from IntelliJ, you will see messages scrolling by in the Run / Debug tab. At the top, there's the command line that is being executed. It should contain the debugger parameters (`-agentlib:jdwp` etc) and it should be followed by a message saying "Connected to the target VM", which is the debugger confirming that it has contact.

Next, if you are unsure if the JVM has been forked, you can check the process list in your OS, for example under MacOS and *nix you can use `ps aux | grep java`. The Java processes typically have a giant parameter list, most of which is the class path. The actual application being run is at the very end of the command line. If the JVM was forked, you have the process running the Maven goal, and another one running the Spring application. Then your debugger will be connected to the process you are *not* interested in, and your breakpoints won't work.

To stop `spring-boot:run` from forking, you can use the `fork` parameter above.

Comment: This resolved it for me. I tried the `JAVA_OPTS` and the `Drun.jvmArguments` without any success.

Comment: This helped me to get over the problem of not being able to debug Spring Boot applications using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Worked perfectly with the Ultimate Edition of Intellij IDEA too with a springboot maven project with spring-boot-maven-plugin plugin... ```jvmArguments=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005``` run debug command-line: ```spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.fork=false -f pom.xml```

Comment: Also un-check the "Delegate do maven" option

Comment: For Spring Boot 3 this no longer works, because the fork option had beed deprecated with 2.7 and is now removed completely. See here: [Spring Boot 3 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide)

Comment: @Ruik So what do we do now?

Comment: I found a workaround. Thanks for the Reminder to post this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75483956/debug-spring-boot-3-in-intellij-community
I also posted this answer on this question but it is very far down.

Answer (score 100):

The only approach that worked for me, is running or debugging application directly from Intellij Idea. Just open class which contains

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
```

And click right mouse button->Debug my application

Comment: It would be interesting to have a look at IntelliJ's console and see what it is actually doing and why that would be different from the other ways to start the application with a debugger attached.

Comment: Idea adds its own debug configuration to JVM and starts debugging on arbitrary port rather then using debug properties pre-defined by you.

Comment: does not work in my case, intellij is still not stopping at breakpoints

Comment: This works for me. My project is springboot rest backend, jar package, with embed tomcat, Idea debug it perfectly!

Comment: That's not the problem described in question.

Comment: @TOUDIdel it is not a problem, it is one of ways to solve it

Answer (score 62):

For me these steps work:

1. Select menu Run -> Edit Configurations...
2. Create new Remote
   Configuration. By default you don't need to change settings:
   *-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005*.
   But if you want for example to suspend JVM before you connects, you
   can change *suspend=y*. Or you can chage port etc.
3. Copy command line depending your JVM version and save configuration.
4. In Terminal window run your app with (in Maven usage case and JVM 1.5 and higher) *mvn clean spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"*
5. Connect to your app by running your Remote Configuration created prviously on step 2. Now you can debug your app.

Comment: In case someone is using copy-paste: `-Drun:jvmArguments=` should be `-Drun.jvmArguments=` (dot instead of colon)

Comment: I actually needed to add this to pom.xml, because spring-boot ignored the -Drun... argument: `<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  <configuration>
    <jvmArguments>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005</jvmArguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>`

Comment: In Intellij you can also go to `Runner` tab in your Run Configuration and paste these arguments (`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005`) into `VM Options` input.

Answer (score 13):

I found that including Spring Dev Tools in my build caused IntelliJ debugging to break (per your description above). If you don't use this feature, then simply remove it from your build.

If using Maven, the lines below should be removed from you pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This import fact is not reflected in spring-devtools documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html . Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

piphonom's anwser is good , but you need do a little more,which is add the jvmArguments to the maven plugin like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <jvmArguments>
            -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
        </jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

for more information about remote debuge for spring boot project, read [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html)

Comment: It was not helpful. Maybe the debug port is random and its not bound by maven plugin configuration

Comment: This worked great for me. The suspend=y caused the build to wait for the debugger to attach, which is great for debugging initialization-related issues as well.

openjdk 15 2020-09-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15+36-1562)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15+36-1562, mixed mode, sharing)

Apache Maven 3.6.3

IntelliJ 2020.3.2

Spring Boot 2.4.2

Answer (score 6):

You can use this workaround in IntelliJ Community edition to debug java application with standard module (through mvn spring-boot:run) without needing to create a dedicated debug listener in intelliJ configuration (it will be created on the fly) :

In the maven menu (by default on the right of the screen), click on the "execute maven goal" button :

[image: click the button the arrow points to]

Then enter this goal:  `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5000"`
(you may want to change the port for the coordination between intelliJ's debugger and your application)

This will start your Spring boot application but it will suspend. In the `run` menu below, you'll see a button `Attach debugger`.

[image: click the button the arrow points to, at the bottom of the image]

Click on it and voilà: your spring-boot application will run and the breakpoints will hit.

NB:the solution provided by @stinger would only work in IntelliJ Idea Ultimate Edition, it will not work in IntelliJ Community Edition, which is the one asked in the question, but I don't have enough reputation yet to add a comment on his answer. @stinger 's solution is yet preferred if you use Ultimate Edition

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working for me (IntelliJ Community Edition). Finally I can debug and learn Java the way I want.

Comment: It works! Unluckily, you lose the Console stdout.

Comment: @MarcoSulla you don't, it's in a different tab

Answer (score 5):

Spring boot maven plugin (> 2.2.0) [forks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.2/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run) application process. So the good old "spring-boot:run" started in debug mode doesn't stop on breakpoints.

You have 2 options:

**1. Directly run main class**
[See application configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykCdc.png)

**2. Remote debugging**

2.1. Configure spring-boot-maven-plugin to [enable remote debug](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.2/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run-example-debug)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>
                -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=**n**,address=5005
                </jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
</build>
```

2.2. Run server
[See maven configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHcPF.png)

2.3. Run debug-server
[See remote JVM debug configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZfsw.png)

Answer (score 4):

1. enable the debug port on your app's pom.XML
   like:

   <plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <configuration>
   <jvmArguments>
   -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
   </jvmArguments>
   </configuration>
   </plugin>

2. follow the Ville Miekk-oja sugestion

   > So go to edit configurations-> Remote -> +. Then start your
   >   application normally through intelliJ. Then switch to the newly
   >   created remote configuration. Instead of running it, press debug. Now
   >   debugger should be ready, and you can set breakpoints and the debugger
   >   will stop to them.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, all the prevoius answers are incomplete. I've spent much time to find the correct way of remote debuging in IntelliJ and here is the full explanation.

We assume that the project code is in your local machine (Windows OS) and you have a deployment of your project on an Ubuntu VM in your server (or your VMWare workstation). and these two machines are in the same network (they can ping eachother)

First of all, add the a new Run/Debug configuration using the menu Run>Edit Configuration and then hit the + button at the top left corner and choose the "Remote" option. Keep the configuration parameters as is and just define a name for your new config.

Secondly, open putty and connect to your remote server over SSH. run below command to add remote debugging feature to your project in the putty terminal:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
```

Now change to your project's root directory on the remote server (in the same putty session) and run it using the command you usually use to do it (mine is as following for example):

```
mvn -U clean spring-boot:run
```

**Here comes the most important part that everybody neglected here :)**

Right click on the top of the putty session window and select "Change Settings.." option. Go to the path Connection>SSH>Tunnels in the left side options tree. Now add two port forwarding records such as the following picture (one Local, which forwards the localhost 5005 port to your remote server IP with the same port number, and one Remote who forwards the remote 5005 port to the 5005 port on localhost machine)

[image]

Finally go back to IntelliJ and from the run menu choose your previously added configuration and then hit the Debug button. Your local IntelliJ IDEA should be connected to the remote deployment of your project now, ready to debug!!

[image]

Comment: This works for me. Thanks! The only difference is that my project already has its JAVA_OPTS, so I end up adding this line to my shell script: `export JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"`

Answer (score 1):

on inteliJ goto run-> edit configuration -> press on the '+' -> choose 'Application'

fill the fields: main class,working directory, classpath of module

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot 3 the `spring-boot.run.fork=false` way no longer works. Unfortunatly this option was removed as you can read in the [Spring Boot 3.0 Migration Guide][1]:

> The fork attribute of spring-boot:run and spring-boot:start that was deprecated in Spring Boot 2.7 has been removed.

Since starting the Spring Boot Main class didn't work for me and attaching a debugger was both complicated and only possible when the server was already running, I found another workaround. It my not be ideal in any cases but probably an easy way for many cases.

I do a `@SpringBootTest` with JUnit and then a test method that just sleeps for one our. That way the Spring Context comes up and stays for debugging. If I let Spring bind to a defined port I can even call REST endpoints.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
class TemplateApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(360000);
    }
}
```

(This is the same answer that I posted to my own question regarding the Spring Boot 3 problem: [Debug Spring Boot 3 in IntelliJ Community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75483956/debug-spring-boot-3-in-intellij-community/75603965#75603965))

Answer (score 0):

For me, I didn't actually have to run my project with mvn spring-boot:run. Instead of debugging with a maven configuration I went to Edit Configurations and added a spring boot configuration with the same parameters as my maven configuration. Out of the box in IntelliJ Idea 2023.3.2 the debugging worked.