# Cannot debug / stop a springboot app with IntelliJ Idea community

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

My Idea setup cannot stop on breakpoints and not even stop the launched/debugged process.

Environment:

- ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- openjdk version "1.8.0_275" 64 bit
- IntelliJ Idea 2020.2

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a maven ["demo" application](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.4.0.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=1.8&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,devtools) from https://start.spring.io/ (Spring Web dependency will suffice)
- Download IntelliJ Idea and launch `idea.sh`
- Open `pom.xml` file to import the project in the IDE
- Add a `@RestController` returning "Hello world" for `@GetMapping("/")`
- Drop a couple of breakpoints in the App and in the newly created controller
- Configure a maven launcher with `spring-boot:run` command line
- Hit the `debug` button

The application launches and you can call `http://localhost` to see the "Hello world"; you can even change the code and the app nicely reloads but ... it does not stop on breakpoints.

When you hit the stop button the IDE detaches from the process but does not stop it.

What's wrong with my setup?

BTW: debugging works smoothly for a simple cli maven java application.

Comment: You should start the execution from your IDE and not from your build tool.. then you simply debug in your IDE...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47064387/509565 I've worked out the solution:

1. Use `spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.fork=false` as your laucher command line
2. Ensure that "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven" in "Build ...> Build Tools > Maven > Runner" settings is NOT checked