# Can we debug springboot application using IntelliJ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, debugging, remote-debugging

I am new to the springboot and currently trying to debug the spring boot application. Is there any way to do thta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question has posted in here[1] as well.
This resource will also helpful for you[2].

Please have a look on these resources. These will be helpful for you.

[1] [How to debug spring-boot application with IntelliJ IDEA community Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096708/how-to-debug-spring-boot-application-with-intellij-idea-community-edition)

[2] https://www.baeldung.com/spring-debugging